# Guarantee the data retrieved from Firebase is not NULL

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I met this error when I tried to consume some data:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not an object (evaluating 'snapshot.docs[0].data')

I think it's due to the emptiness of the dataset although I'm the admin of my org's Firebase account. So to be more robust, what can I do to my code? For example, how can I set the default value (i.e. empty string "") if value `undefined` is detected?

```
import { AuthContext } from "./Auth/Auth";

function Transfer() {
    const [type, setType] = useState([]);
    const {currentUser} = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(currentUser){
            firebaseApp.firestore()
            .collection("User")
            .where("userEmail", "==", currentUser.email)
            .get()
            .then(snapshot => 
                setType(snapshot.docs[0].data().userType)
            );
        }
        

    }, [type])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
const userInfo = snapshot.docs[0].data()
setType(userInfo?.userType || "")
```

Comment: Can you explain this syntax please?

Comment: It is Optional chaining (?.) you can search for MDN docs :D

Comment: Thank you! [Link to docs for anyone else interested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: sorry my company block this link so I cant share you a link , just can share a keyword  :<
have a nice day :D

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: @AnhTuan I tried it back then. Unfortunately the error still exists.

Comment: @MemphisMeng what is your problem